# Wrong result in fetching User meta of WordPress

Tags: user-meta, wp-user-query

I have custom post type `Task` where I assigned Users as Volunteers.

[image]

Now I would like to fetch `how many tasks assigned to a Volunteer.`

I am using below code.

```
$users = new WP_User_Query(array(
        'meta_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
                'key' => 'last_name',
                'value' => $_POST['search'],
                'compare' => 'LIKE',
            ),
        ),
    ));
    $users_found = $users->get_results();


    $names = array();
    foreach ($users_found as $user) {
        $this_users_tasks = get_user_meta($user->ID,'task',false);
        $names[$user->ID] = $user->display_name.' ('.count($this_users_tasks).')';
    }

    
    echo json_encode($names);
    die;
```

But I am getting wrong result.

Comment: Wrong how? How are you assigning tasks to users? Your code uses a single `task` meta key on the user? Is that how?

Comment: Thanks @JacobPeattie. I attached a screenshot. I hope you can get idea from there.

Comment: @JacobPeattie. Actually I am new in WordPress Development.

Comment: @JacobPeattie. Yes, I am assigning tasks to users.

Comment: The screenshot doesn’t explain how the data is connected. Are you using Pods to create these fields? If so you need to consult the Pods documentation. Third party plugins are off topic here.

Comment: Thanks @JacobPeattie. Yes, I used Pods.

Comment: You have chaotic `WP_User_Query` parameters. I haven't tested them, but using `'relation' => 'OR'` in your case can possibly result in "_This_ OR _Everything_'", so any of them is _true_. There is no any relation in your case. Rethink the query.